# We are trying to Automate some tests for Salesforce Lightning page and I am getting "login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect." error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce-lightning

Visual Studio c#, selenium code.
Using Selenium Web-driver chrome driver and trying to open Salesforce Lightning page.
When I go to Activities screen getting "login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect." error.
Checked the developers tools and see the message X-Frame set to Deny.
Switched to Salesforce Classic and I don't see the issue.

When I try to open Salesforce Lightning with my local chrome browser instance everything works fine. The only issue is with Web-drive Chrome instance.

Can any one help me how can I make X-Frame set to Allow.

Comment: Some websites can detect when the instance of the chrome is an automated selenium instance and refuse the connection. That might be the case with microsoft.

Comment: Thank you! for the response. Is there anyway to accept the connection?

Comment: You can have some workarounds but since that's probably a validation inside the Salesforce itself I can't think a way to make that work in a reliable way.